# End the GUI on TTY7, and start a new one elsewhere

Tags: gui, tty

How can I end the GUI from a different TTY, then start up a new one.

This is for the occasional freeze of the GUI, or inaccessibility. When all I can do is switch to another TTY (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for TTY5) and start over, or reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much easier way to restart the GUI.

In most cases you can just use:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't have any effect for me on XUbuntu 15.

Answer (score 4):

## How to restart the display manager

If X is hung, you should be able rejigger it by restarting the display manager. In 11.10, it's lightdm, recent past versions use gdm. Change the following examples as appropriate for your version. You can restart it a few different ways. I prefer the simplicity of the `restart`:

```
sudo restart gdm
```

Or you can use the `service` command:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

Init script hackers stuck on sysv will prefer `invoke-rc.d`:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d gdm restart
```

## If it's really hung..

If restarting the display manager doesn't work, pull out a hammer and kill it dead with one or both of these commands:

```
sudo pkill -9 X
sudo pkill -9 gdm
```

## Which example should I use? Does it matter?

Use the first one. `restart` is a link to `initctl`, which is Upstart, which is Ubuntu's init manager that they are trying to convert everything over to.

The other two commands, `service` and `invoke-rc.d` are there only to control the old-style SysV init scripts. SysV exists in modern Ubuntu *only* for backwards compatibility. Don't rely on it. But if you must..

`service` is for end-users. It returns a simple exit code. If you're a normal user needing to control a SysV style init script, use this tool.

`invoke-rc.d` is for init script hackers. It returns a bunch of varied and useful exit codes. There's no reason a normal user should use this tool. There isn't any harm for normal users, it's just more complicated.

Comment: Note that as of 11.10 you should restart/kill lightdm rather than gdm.

Comment: @HamishDowner As noted in the second sentence : )

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pkill X` does the job for me

Answer (score 0):

Try `invoke-rc.d gdm restart` as root.

Comment: I haven't tested that command on Ubuntu, but it works on Debian Squeeze

Comment: While this command works, it's intended for people hacking on init scripts. The end-user variant, what your answer should recommend instead, is `service`.

Comment: Voted up your reply. Those small differences between Debian and Ubuntu is the difference between power user and user ;)

Answer (score 0):

If CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE doesn't end the current X server and plop you back in lightdm or gdm then there is an alternate sequence (which I've personally never tried) that goes like this: [ALT+PrintScreen+R-E-I-S-U-B](http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/05/howto-restart-ubuntu-safely-when-it-is.html), however this will actually reboot the machine. My preferred method is to just CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to a terminal and then `sudo service gdm restart` and that will also bring you back to the login screen

Comment: On Ubuntu 11.10, shouldn't you run `sudo service lightdm restart`?

Comment: Advocating a magic sysreq reboot is a terrible answer to this question, just short of "Pull the power plug". Recommending `service` is great though.

Comment: @djeikyb, the ALT+Printscreen is leagues better than pulling the plug because it safely sends SIGTERM and SIGKILL and unmounts filesystems. That's why I recommended CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE first and followed up by saying I personally don't use the ALT+Printscreen.

Comment: @jakob, yes lightdm is now the default, but some people replace it with gdm or otherwise.

Comment: In this context I refer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes), which is helpful to "expand the context".

Comment: Really this should be flagged as a duplicate as the question you linked to is far more comprehensive and fits this question exactly.